# Check for days that are weekdays and not weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm looking for:

Is [Status.SchedFundingDate] on or before [today]+[1 business day]

For that I got:

```
convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 1, 112)
```

My current query that I’m trying to figure out:

Is [Status.SchedFundingDate] on or before [today]+[1 calendar day]

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(DATENAME(DW, getdate())) = 'FRIDAY'
THEN convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 3, 112)
ELSE convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 1, 112)
END
```

The above SQL statement is giving me syntax errors on the ‘<’ symbols.

Comment: Because CASE is an expression in TSql, not a control of flow construct as it is in many other languages. And converting dates (or datetimes) to string for comparison is the wrong approach to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the comparisons on `SELECT`. SQL Server doesn't know what is a boolean, you have to use `BIT`.

For example `SELECT 1 < 0` is invalid and gives you the same error `Incorrect syntax near '<'.`.

On SQL Server you must do something like:

```
SELECT  CAST(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' AND [Status.SchedFundingDate] <= GETDATE() + 3 
                THEN 1
             WHEN [Status.SchedFundingDate] <= GETDATE() + 1
                THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS BIT);
```

Comment: You should cast the result to bit otherwise it is int

Comment: I tried casting it and it didn't like the 'as' part.

Comment: How did you cast and what error you got? The syntax is `SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT);` if you want boolean.

Comment: I'm writing in T-SQL, I'm getting an error saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

CASE WHEN cast((DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) = 'Friday' AND [Status.SchedFundingDate] <= GETDATE() + 3) as bit)
                THEN convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 3, 112)
             WHEN [Status.SchedFundingDate] <= GETDATE() + 1
                THEN convert(varchar(10), [Status.SchedFundingDate], 112) <= convert(varchar(10), getdate() + 1, 112)
             ELSE 0
        END

Comment: @razimovom I edited the answer to include the `CAST` to `BIT`. Please, read the [docs on CASE expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [CAST expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get a better understanding of both.

Comment: @marcos Thank you, I went over both but now it's telling me - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

Answer (score 0):

`( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, YourDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

You can use that in a `case` expression to adjust a date for weekends by adding the needed number of days:

```
-- Generate some sample data.
with Dates as (
  select GetDate() as ADate, 1 as NumberOfDates
  union all
  select DateAdd( day, 1, ADate ), NumberOfDates + 1
    from Dates
    where NumberOfDates <= 14 )
  -- Demonstrate adjusting weekend dates to the next Monday.
  select ADate, DateName( weekday, ADate ) as Weekday,
    DateAdd( day, case ( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, ADate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1
      when 1 then 1 -- Sunday.
      when 7 then 2 -- Saturday.
      else 0 end, ADate ) as AdjustedADate
    from Dates;
```